# Why does convert depend on the obsolete libg2c.so.0? How to get it to work again?

Tags: imagemagick

When I try to run

```
convert file.bmp file.jpg
```

I get the following error message:

```
convert: error while loading shared libraries: libg2c.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried looking for that library in synaptic, but I could not identify any package, that provides `libg2c.so.0`. In [How do I install libg2c](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300957/how-do-i-install-libg2c-on-ubuntu) it is stated somewhere in the comments that this library is not in the repositories since Hardy.

Why does a standard tool like `convert`, that is shipped with `imagemagick`, depend on that library when it is not available any more?

Therefore should I try to find the library and install it? Or is this tool obsolete by now? (Why is it still in the repositories?) Is there any workaround to using convert again? Is there any command line tool with the same functionality as an alternative?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS with XFCE 4.8 inside a virtual machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install libg2c on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/300957/how-do-i-install-libg2c-on-ubuntu)

Comment: @Danatela I found this question and that hardly gives any solution to the problem a hand. I will try to reformulate the question and would very much appreciate if this could be reopened after that.

Comment: You shouldn't worry. You have only 2 close votes while 5 required. Sorry for giving you wrong clue. There is [another solution around the Internet](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-install-libg2c-in-ubuntu-4175473830/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[convert does not depend on libg2c](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/imagemagick). Try re-installing:

```
apt-get purge imagemagick
apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: I tried that without improvement.

Comment: What is the output of `which convert`? and `ls -l /etc/alternatives/convert` and `ldd $(which convert)` and `update-alternatives --display convert`?

Comment: That was exactly the problem, it points to the wrong executable.