# tetview error while loading shared libraries: libg2c.so.0

Tags: software-installation

First I tried to use tetview on ubuntu 14.04 64bit. There I ran into problems because it needs 32 bit libraries, tried to fix it wit no luck.

Now I am trying to run it on ubuntu 14.04 32 bit.

```
./tetview-linux: error while loading shared libraries: libg2c.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After trying the first answer at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300957/how-do-i-install-libg2c) question the problem is the following:

```
./tetview-linux: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And to fix this issue ubuntu asks to remove the previously installed libg2c.so.0

Answer (score 0):

On fresh 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

1. Downloading: 
    
   libg2c0_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_i386.deb [from here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-3.4/libg2c0_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_i386.deb) 
    
   libstdc++5_3.3.6-18_i386.deb [from here](http://archive.debian.net/lenny/i386/libstdc++5/download)
2. Extract with Archive Manager
3. Copy files to the right location

   `$ sudo cp ~/Downloads/libg2c0_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_i386/usr/lib/* /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
   $ sudo cp ~/Downloads/libstdc++5_3.3.6-18_i386/usr/lib/* /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`

Comment: Is it possible for this to work for 64-bit Ubuntu?

Comment: I am not sure, there isn't documentation on it.