# How to install libg2c.so.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 64bit

Tags: gcc, glibc

I'm using:

```
Linux ip-172-31-28-209 5.4.0-1059-aws #62~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 22 21:51:38 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I encounter an error while running a program:

`while loading shared libraries: libg2c.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS3`2

How can I resolve it?

I looked at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300957/how-do-i-install-libg2c), but it's for 32bit version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even after 13 years this 64-bit library can be installed by direct [download](https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-3.4/) using commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-3.4/gcc-3.4-base_3.4.6-6ubuntu3_amd64.deb
wget -c https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-3.4/libg2c0_3.4.6-6ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./gcc-3.4-base_3.4.6-6ubuntu3_amd64.deb ./libg2c0_3.4.6-6ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```